# Error on calling enterVR() on a-scene (chromium and nightly desktop)

Tags: aframe

I have been having issues when trying to call enterVR() on my a-scene element from within my JS code. Whether I wait for the scene to have loaded or bind enterVR() to a vive controller input, I get the following error:

`Error: Failed to enter VR mode ('requestPresent'): API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`

I have been using the latest chromium experimental build as well as Mozilla Nightly and the following Aframe version(master) :0.5.0 (Date 22-03-2017, Commit #bc6be7c).

Ultimately, my only goal is to begin presenting content to the headset as soon as the scene has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need a user gesture like a click to enter VR. If you do it within a 'window.addEventListener('click', ...)', it should work